# What are the different inbuilt responsive widgets in flutter framework?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Like the framework provided `AboutDialog` responsive widget what are the other such inbuilt responsive widgets in flutter framework?

Comment: what do you mean by responsive widgets?

Comment: Take a look at this use of AboutDialog. Try to resize the page and pay attention the the license details panel - https://tonicartos.github.io/flutter-new-license-page/#/

Answer (score -1):

LayoutBuilder

AspectRatio

CustomSingleChildLayout

CustomMultiChildLayout

FittedBox

FractionallySizedBox

LayoutBuilder

MediaQuery

MediaQueryData

OrientationBuilder

[See this page](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/responsive) to learn more about creating responsive apps.

Comment: These are not responsive. These are used to achieve responsiveness.

Comment: Well, that's your job as the developer. There is no magic widget.

Comment: Then what is it about ? There is no responsive widgets per se, just useful widgets and classes for creating a responsive UI.

Comment: There is one i know of - AboutDialog. And my question is if there are more like that inside the framework.

Comment: How is AboutDialog responsive ? You mean that the text adapts to the width ?